# How to remove all items from NSCollectionView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to remove all the items that user has added in `NSCollectionView` by removing all items from `NSMutableArray`. It's not working.

I just need to **Refresh/Reload** by **Clear/Remove** all items of the `NSCollectionView`

Comment: Call reloadData on your collection view.

Comment: Its working and updating if I am reloading data however if I need to clear all the items from the NSCollecitonView only then its not getting updated. I have solved the issue by removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndex. Thanks for reply @Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSIndexSet* selectedIndexSet = [_lablesCollectionView selectionIndexes];
NSUInteger index = [selectedIndexSet firstIndex] ;
NSLog(@"index is %d", index);
[lablesArray removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes:selectedIndexSet];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: // solution: 
 for (int i = 0; i < [[arrayController arrangedObjects] count]; i++) {
        [arrayController removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndex:i];
        i--;
    }

Answer (score 1):

//remove/clear all items from NSCollectionView

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [[arrayController arrangedObjects] count]; i++) {
        [arrayController removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndex:i];
        i--;
    }
```

Comment: Note that `i` will always be 0 in this code. You could simplify it as just: `while (arrayController.arrangedObject.count > 0) { [arrayController removeObjectAtArrangeObjectIndex:0]; }`